# ChannelAdvisor GZIP webhooks with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, gzip, webhooks, channeladvisor

I am trying to use the new ChannelAdvisor webhooks but the header Content-Encoding comes through as gzip.  So when I try to retrieve the content from the HTTP POST using getHTTPRequestData().content it gives the following bad data:

> ïœSÞ®SK‚WPŒÅcåÝPòXÊ°üwYÀ£´ÙéªŠ7ä1«7ØÑq9zVŒÒ

How do I force ColdFusion to download the GZIP into a file?  And how do I read that file.  I believe reading the GZIP file should work based on the following link but I've yet to have success with downloading the file.

http://coldfusion-tip.blogspot.com/search/label/UnZip%20.gz

Comment: Did you try the `<cfzip?` tag?

Comment: ColdFusion cannot unzip gzip files based on the online comments I've read.

Comment: This is the documentation from ChannelAdvisor:  Requests are GZip Encoded

Webhooks responses are gzip encoded and need to be unzipped prior to reading/consuming the payload.

Ensure your endpoint is capable of unzipping the request.

This is the default GZip content encoding for HTTP requests. ChannelAdvisor API uses the standard Deflate format, which uses a combination of LZ77 and Huffman coding.